# New resistance calculation after increasing wattage

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

I have some small lights in series (similar to the ones for Christmas,) normal ones not LED. They are powered with 3 batteries of 1.5 V and in series there is a resistor of 7.5 ohms (1 W I believe.)

I want to switch to a 5 V DC power source and remove the batteries. I did it initially directly without changing anything but I almost burned the resistor (it became black.) I then measured the output of the power source and actually is outputting 9.3 V.

How can I calculate the new resistance I need to give to the bulbs the same energy they were receiving before?

Please correct anything you think is incorrect:

1. Given that bulbs have variable resistance I firstly calculated the current in the old circuit: 0.13 A.
2. The resistor of 7.5 ohms was actually a 8.4 Ohms with multimeter
3. batteries of 1.5 V were outputting 4.86 V
4. I firstly calculated the voltage drop across the Resistor (V = 0.13 * 8.4 = 1.092)
5. By subtraction I calculated the voltage drop across the bulbs 4.86 - 1.092 = 3.768 V
6. I then calculated the resistance of the bulbs when 0.13 A are applied: R = 3.768/0.13 = 28.98 Ohms.
7. Now I want to to switch to a DC power input of 9.3 V. I thought that the new circuit must have the same current of 0.13 A if I don't want to destroy the bulbs hence I calculated the total resistance of the circuit when I apply 9.15 V: R = 9.15/0.13 = 70.38 Ohms
8. Which means that if the current is same the bulbs must have the same resistance of earlier (28.98 Ohms). Hence I calculated that the new resistance should be 70.38 - 28.98 = 41.4 Ohms
9. I bought a 39 Ohms resistance and switched it with the old one, but after measuring the current in the circuit I got only 0.7 A
10. Randomly I plugged a 9.3 Ohms resistance and I got 0.16 A which is way better and closer to the old circuit.
11. So I deducted that my calculation is wrong :)

PS: I also calculated the wattage of the new resistor with the following formula: 5.382^2/41.4 = 0.7 W so I bought a 1 W resistor of 39 Ohms.

Comment: Use a voltage regulator.

Comment: Thanks Andy, yes this is an option too, but now I am also curious how to solve the original problem...I already made some calculations but at the end, when testing with multimeter, they turned out to be wrong

Comment: Does voltage regulator need heat-sink?

Comment: Show us the calculations you did, and explain what testing you did, and explain why you think the calculations were wrong.

Comment: Of your 5V piwer supply outputs 9.3V ypu need to change that.

Comment: Your 5V DC power supply is unregulated. Change the supply to a regulated 5V DC power supply or calculate a suitable new resistor.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your support. Please I edited my question with the calculation I performed. I am learning so I could have said a lot of incorrect things :)

Comment: @Justme yes I am trying to find the "suitable resistor" but it seems my calculations were wrong. How can I do it?

Comment: How did you calculate the current in step 1? Is it 0.13A or 0.16A?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson with a multimeter, in series ( I broke the circuit and connected the multimeter). 0.13A in the old/original circuit with resistor of 7.5Ohms (which actually was 8.a when measured with multimeter). 0.16A I got when I plugged a 9.3Ohms resistor instead of the 7.5. And 0.7A I got when I substituted the 7.5Ohms with the 39Ohms calculated.

Comment: Your measurements don't make sense to me. You say that the current is going up when you use a larger resistance. How could the current be 0.7A without destroying the bulbs?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, yes is going up with a larger resistance because with the larger resistance I also increase the input Vatt from 4.5V to 9.3V...I think I omitted it in the steps but I mentioned above I want to change from batteries to DC of 9.3V

Comment: please read again point 7 modified

Comment: point 9 .. `I got only 0.7A` ... this implies that you were expecting a higher value ... what reading were you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting 0.13A which was the current in the original circuit with old resistor of 7.5 and input of 4.5V (point 1)